# How can I assess the health of my iPhone 5 battery?

Tags: iphone, battery

I suspect my iPhone's battery is now much worse than it used to be.
How can I assess this? Is there some kind of test I can make, to compare it with Industry average?

How long can I reproduce a movie, a specific app, or something like that?